# Binomial Expansion without infinity series [Duplicated]

Tags: binomial-theorem

(This is duplicated due do the lack of answers in the previous asking session,because I edited the unreadable math too long that this got lost in "recent questions".I was unable to delete the previous one.)

Variable here is "a" and "b".The question is to simplify the $\sqrt [3] { (\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^3} })\times {\frac {\sqrt{a^6b^2}}{a} }+ \frac{a}{b^2}}$

So these are my steps

=$\left(\frac {a^3b} {b^\frac {3} {2} }+ \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

=$\left({a^3b^{1-\frac {3} {2}} } + \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

=$\left({a^3b^\frac {-1} {2} } + \frac {a} {b^2}\right)^\frac {1} {3}$

Now the real question is,how to simplify this?Assuming the both fraction is simplified to "x" and "y",I get $(x+y)^\frac {1} {3}$ but my family said that it is expanded to this:

$(x+y)^\frac {1} {3}=x^\frac {1} {3}+y^\frac {1} {3}$
It should not be this because $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$

The thing is I noticed where $(x+y)^n$ have a pattern called pascal triangle.But this can be only applied when n≥1 where n is a integer.

The problem with the binomial theorem is that the answer is infinite,which I do not want to get this.I need to get an answer where it is not infinite and does not involve any roots.How do I simplify this?

I have checked with Issac Newton theory,but the Issac Newton theory is infinite.

I have searched online and I see is infinite answer: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054926/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54582.html)

(And by the way,even if I put it as a single fraction,$\left( \frac {a^3b^\frac {1} {2}+a} {b^2} \right)^\frac {1} {3}$,it still encounters the same problem.)

If this is impossible to simplify without avoiding infinite series,is there another method to solve the question,$\sqrt [3] { (\frac{a}{\sqrt{b^3} })\times {\frac {\sqrt{a^6b^2}}{a} }+ \frac{a}{b^2}}$?

Comment: What you got just before you write "Now, the real question..." is the best you can hope for. Any more dwelling on this could make things simpler...or messier, depending on who's reading. What you say your family said is complete nonsense, of course.

Comment: @Timbuc I dont get it.Is it because I am asking too complicating or the question is almost impossible to answer

Comment: There is no question "to answer" here: simplification, unless something very simple is given, really does depend on each one. You have already simplified (i.e., made smaller) exponents, you could even write one single fraction within the cubic square: there is no one single, unique, perfect answer to such question as yours.

Comment: @Timbuc Do you mean I have answered my ownself?

Comment: As far as I can see you really have.

Comment: @Timbuc Shouldn't the meaning of simplification in mathematics is to remove the brackets or to prevent (Power of) roots?Sorry,a 13 year old here.Might not understand things easily

Comment: Yes, simplification could mean what you say...when reasonably possible within every one's possibilities. You can't use Taylor/power series as you mention with Newton's method or the link you put, because these are methods for calculus, which you haven't yet studied (unless you're an advanced student well into high school). Thus, in this case, "simplification" may just mean just to make things more easily readable.

Comment: @Timbuc I would want advanced methods that could solve this.No matter how complicating it is.If I cant understand,I will research on my own to understand

Comment: Good...I guess. Then google or search in books "Taylor polynomial" and then "Taylor series" .

Comment: @Timbuc Okay got it.